# How to prove the non-degeneracy of this Schrödinger equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, symmetry

How to prove that under the potential like$V(x) = -\frac{\nu}{2}x^2 + \frac{\beta}{4}x^4$, in which $\nu, \beta >0$, the system has no degeneracy? That is to say the Schrödinger equation
$-\partial^2\Psi/\partial x^2 +V(x) \Psi = E\Psi$ has no degenerate level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a general fact that in a one dimensional system, bound states cannot be degenerate. To see this, suppose the opposite statement is true. So corresponding to a certain energy eigenvalue $E$, there exist at least two linearly independent states satisfying
\begin{align}
  -\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\dfrac{d^2\psi_1}{dx^2}=(E-V)\psi_1\tag{1}\\
  -\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\dfrac{d^2\psi_2}{dx^2}=(E-V)\psi_2\tag{2}
\end{align}
And $(1)\times \psi_2-(2)\times \psi_1$ yields
\begin{equation}
  \dfrac{d}{dx}(\psi_2\psi_1^\prime-\psi_1\psi_2^\prime)=0\tag{3}
\end{equation}
because they're bound states, $\psi_1,\psi_2$ and their derivatives vanish at infinity, so $(3)$ says that
$$
  \psi_2\psi_1^\prime-\psi_1\psi_2^\prime=0
$$
or
$$
  \mathrm{ln}\psi_1=\mathrm{ln}\psi_2+\mathrm{const}\Longrightarrow
  \psi_1=\mathrm{const}\cdot \psi_2
$$
which contradicts with our assumption.

Since your potential only allows bound states, the energy levels must be non-degenerate.